# Forecasting next 12 months based on previous data using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm having trouble doing a forecast based on previous data. I have data that represents eight years worth of monthly data $(n=96)$, for number of sales. I want to forecast the next 12 months based on this data using an optimal linear forecast, and I want to provide the variance of this forecast.

Here is the data

```
-1.96
-2.3
-2.61
-2.62
-2.38
-1.9
-1.35
-0.98
-0.65
-0.53
-0.82
-1.19
-1.39
-1.19
-0.93
-1.11
-1.51
-1.8
-1.43
-0.79
0.05
0.36
0.58
0.44
-0.15
-0.88
-1.54
-1.93
-2.18
-1.88
-1.43
-1.15
-1.48
-1.47
-1.24
-0.97
-0.65
-0.37
-0.24
-0.07
-0.09
0.4
0.83
0.98
0.96
0.29
-0.13
-0.94
-1.16
-0.37
0.05
0.18
-0.53
-0.91
-1.11
-1.28
-1.34
-1.64
-1.06
-0.15
0.34
0.14
0.42
0.44
0.05
-0.83
-1.54
-1.58
-1.27
-1.58
-1.37
-0.74
-0.72
-0.77
-1.21
-1.8
-1.74
-1.3
-0.56
0.15
0.86
1.39
2.05
2.24
2.08
1.58
1.23
0.64
0.34
0.34
0.71
1.23
1.69
1.78
2.03
2.13
```

I want to forecast this using either an AR, MA, or ARMA model in R but am not completely sure how to approach this. I know I need to estimate the autocovariance matrix, and I will make the assumption that the autocovariance is zero at lag h > 36. I'm also struggling with what order of the model to use.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
> summary(arima_model)
Series: x_ts 
ARIMA(2,1,1)                               

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1
      1.4366  -0.6947  -0.7568
s.e.  0.1136   0.0758   0.1472

sigma^2 estimated as 0.09159:  log likelihood=-20.28
AIC=48.55   AICc=49   BIC=58.77

Training set error measures:
                     ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.03881399 0.2962634 0.2362755 -10.45825 59.95316 0.2036648 0.03830788
```

**Residuals:**
[image]

**Residual ACF:**
[image]

**Update: using automated ARIMA fit**

```
arima_model <- auto.arima(y = x_ts
                          , d = NA
                          , D = NA
                          , max.p = 5
                          , max.q = 5
                          , max.P = 2
                          , max.Q = 2
                          , max.order = 5
                          , max.d = 2
                          , max.D = 1
                          , start.p = 2
                          , start.q = 2
                          , start.P = 1
                          , start.Q = 1
                          , stationary = FALSE
                          , seasonal = TRUE
                          , ic = "bic"
                          , stepwise = F
                          , trace = T
                          , allowdrift = TRUE
                          , allowmean = TRUE)

summary(arima_model)
Series: x_ts 
ARIMA(2,1,1)                               

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1
      1.4366  -0.6947  -0.7568
s.e.  0.1136   0.0758   0.1472

sigma^2 estimated as 0.09159:  log likelihood=-20.28
AIC=48.55   AICc=49   BIC=58.77

Training set error measures:
                     ME      RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.03881399 0.2962634 0.2362755 -10.45825 59.95316 0.2036648 0.03830788
```

What about that approach?

I study non-stationarity just visually.

I then take first differences.

I don't see a 12-month lag significant `acf`, so I decide not to use the seasonal part.

I build `Arima` manually as follows:

- time-series is differenced once
- there are 2 lags showing significant `acf`
- I try with and without moving average (I judge by the residual `acf`)
- I try include drift or not (I judge by the SE of its coefficient)
- I study `summary` and `acf(resids)`

Finally I plot it.

```
x <- c(-1.96
      ,-2.3
      ,-2.61
      ,-2.62
      ,-2.38
      ,-1.9
      ,-1.35
      ,-0.98
      ,-0.65
      ,-0.53
      ,-0.82
      ,-1.19
      ,-1.39
      ,-1.19
      ,-0.93
      ,-1.11
      ,-1.51
      ,-1.8
      ,-1.43
      ,-0.79
      ,0.05
      ,0.36
      ,0.58
      ,0.44
      ,-0.15
      ,-0.88
      ,-1.54
      ,-1.93
      ,-2.18
      ,-1.88
      ,-1.43
      ,-1.15
      ,-1.48
      ,-1.47
      ,-1.24
      ,-0.97
      ,-0.65
      ,-0.37
      ,-0.24
      ,-0.07
      ,-0.09
      ,0.4
      ,0.83
      ,0.98
      ,0.96
      ,0.29
      ,-0.13
      ,-0.94
      ,-1.16
      ,-0.37
      ,0.05
      ,0.18
      ,-0.53
      ,-0.91
      ,-1.11
      ,-1.28
      ,-1.34
      ,-1.64
      ,-1.06
      ,-0.15
      ,0.34
      ,0.14
      ,0.42
      ,0.44
      ,0.05
      ,-0.83
      ,-1.54
      ,-1.58
      ,-1.27
      ,-1.58
      ,-1.37
      ,-0.74
      ,-0.72
      ,-0.77
      ,-1.21
      ,-1.8
      ,-1.74
      ,-1.3
      ,-0.56
      ,0.15
      ,0.86
      ,1.39
      ,2.05
      ,2.24
      ,2.08
      ,1.58
      ,1.23
      ,0.64
      ,0.34
      ,0.34
      ,0.71
      ,1.23
      ,1.69
      ,1.78
      ,2.03
      ,2.13)

plot(x, type = 'l')

summary(x)

acf(x)

x_diff <- diff(x)

acf(x_diff)
pacf(x_diff)

require(forecast)

x_ts <- stats::ts(data = x
                , frequency = 12)

arima_model <- forecast::Arima(y = x_ts
                             , order = c(2L, 1L, 1L)
                             #, seasonal = list(order = c(1L, 1L, 1L), period = 12)
                             , include.mean = T
                             , include.drift = F

                             )

summary(arima_model)

#plot(arima_model)

resids <- arima_model$residuals

acf(resids)
pacf(resids)     

forecast_arima <- forecast(arima_model, h = 12)
plot(forecast_arima)
```

Comment: Please post a plot of your residuals ... and their acf ....

Comment: @IrishStat, I will, thank you. I am out of office though. The residuals look quite well.

Comment: even better post your residuals to the web or email them to me and I will critically evaluate them

Comment: @IrishStat, yes Sir. Thank you. Tomorrow I willl do. As a coincidence I am enjoying Guinnes and Jameson right now.

Comment: if you are Ireland .... I may have a few hints for you ....call me if you wish ..

Comment: get the jamespn CASKMATE

Comment: @IrishStat, I have Caskmate available, but I am in Saint Petersburg, Russia. Thanks ) I thivk I will manage one more J this night.

Comment: I was in St. Petersburg in August for a few days .

Comment: Your approach is basically http://autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/build-or-make-your-own-arima-forecasting-model ref;lects the 1976 version of AUTOBJ  . Since that time major changes have been incorporated into the iterative identification process. Issues like the presence of Pulses/level shifts/seasonal pulses/local time trends AND data that that exhibits non-constancy in either the parameters or error variance have lead to an augmented flowchart.

Comment: notice the level shift (upwards) in your residuals starting at about period 77 also notice that your ma(1) coefficient nearly cancels your differencing operator as no differencing is needed . notice your ar(2) structure is nearly identical to the AUTOBOX coefficients.

Comment: also note your error variance ,09159 is larger than AUTOBOX;'s .0808

Comment: @IrishStat, thank you, Sir! I also tried auto arima fit, and it has worked just like me.

Comment: the reason that auto,arima overmodels is that it is not an iterative process AND relies on trying a fixed set of models. In this case the information extraction i.e. the identification of unusual activity 1) level shift at 77 2) a seasonal pulse starting at period 45 and 3) a pulse at 62 is quite interesting and possibly important in detecting unusual activity. If you want you can contact me via skype to continue this important dialogue

Comment: @IrishStat, thank you. Did you propose AR(2) model? We can surely discuss this later on via Skype or in chat here. Thanks Sir!

Comment: yes an AR(2) model was suggested with coefficients 1.6067 and -.75 as compared to your 1,4366 and -.6947. You can SKYPE me by searching for  dave@autobox.com

Answer (score 0):

Your data suggests an[image] AR(2) model with a (visually obvious ) level shift at period 77 and 1 unusual observation at period 62  ....   [image]    and [image]  . The residuals are free of structure [image] also [image] . The ACTUAL/CLEANSED graph is o[image]f interest . The ACTUAL/FIT/FORECAST is here [image]

The forecast confidence intervals are here using monte carlo methods allowing for future anomalies to be possible ...[image]

A presumptive (but traditional) approach wold be just to use the model variance and the psi weights and a critical assumption of the errors being normal to create SYMMETRIC limits free of any future pulses.

Hope this helps

As to why you think you need to compute auto-covariances to get limits, I can only surmise that this was the suggested way for you to deal with the psi weights which incorporate the boot-strapping auto-projective aspect to the forecasts.

By the way , AUTOBOX easily interfaces with R .